# Laptop power button not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: suspend, shutdown, hp

I recently purchased latest HP Omen 15 laptop and installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it. My problem is that I cannot shutdown or suspend using physical power button, pressing button does nothing. The power button works fine when I want to turn on my laptop. Can anyone suggest a solution to this? This is how my settings look like:
[image: power button settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to push the power button for more than one second? It needs some time to trigger the event. It works for me as I described on Lenovo ThinkPad T480s and Ubuntu 20.04.